# Getting multiple column values in single row

Tags: oracle, multiple-columns, listagg

This is my actual result and i have used for store details of client

```
    SID       ATTRIBUTE_VALUES   ATTRIBUTE_ID      
    ---------- ----------------   -----------
    20         101010             MEMBERSHIP_NO 
    20         ALLEN              MEMBERSHIP_NAME
    20         WARD               MEMBERSHIP_LNAME
    30         101011             MEMBERSHIP_NO
    30         MARTIN             MEMBERSHIP_NAME
    30         BLAKE              MEMBERSHIP_LNAME
```

In this I need to retrieve the details based on membership no and also using sid. sid is unique number .
I need to show the result as

```
    SID MEMBERSHIP_NO MEMBERSHIP_NAME MEMBERSHIP_LNAME
    -----   ------------- --------------- ----------------
    20      101010        ALLEN           WARD
    30      101011        MARTIN          BLAKE
```

Above 3 attributes are constant using that values only client number, names are inserts into table. Im stuck with this...I need to solution for it.

This is the query i have used for retrieve the details. But it returns empty

```
    SELECT sid,  LISTAGG(attribute_value, ',') WITHIN GROUP 
    (ORDER BY attribute_value) AS att FROM customer_attributes WHERE 
    sid ='20' AND attribute_value='101010'
    AND attribute_id ='MEMBERSHIP_NO'
    AND attribute_id ='MEMBERSHIP_NAME'
    AND attribute_id ='MEMBERSHIP_LNAME'
    GROUP BY SID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by `join`. [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)  wont  create 3 columns:

```
select 
    a.sid,
    a.ATTRIBUTE_VALUES MEMBERSHIP_NO,
    b.ATTRIBUTE_VALUES MEMBERSHIP_NAME,
    c.ATTRIBUTE_VALUES MEMBERSHIP_LNAME
from tbl a 
join tbl b on a.sid = b.sid
join tbl c on c.sid = b.sid
where a.ATTRIBUTE_ID = 'MEMBERSHIP_NO'
and b.ATTRIBUTE_ID = 'MEMBERSHIP_NAME'
and c.ATTRIBUTE_ID = 'MEMBERSHIP_LNAME'
```

**Demo** [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/feb16/3)

This also gives the same result;

```
select 
    sid,
    Max(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_ID, 'MEMBERSHIP_NO', ATTRIBUTE_VALUES, '')) MEMBERSHIP_NO,
    Max(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_ID, 'MEMBERSHIP_NAME', ATTRIBUTE_VALUES, '')) MEMBERSHIP_NAME,
    Max(DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_ID, 'MEMBERSHIP_LNAME', ATTRIBUTE_VALUES, '')) MEMBERSHIP_LNAME
from tbl 
group by sid
order by sid
```

Same can be done by [Pivot](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) also

```
select *
from tbl
pivot(
    max(ATTRIBUTE_VALUES) for ATTRIBUTE_ID in (
        'MEMBERSHIP_NO' MEMBERSHIP_NO, 
        'MEMBERSHIP_NAME' MEMBERSHIP_NAME, 
        'MEMBERSHIP_LNAME' MEMBERSHIP_LNAME
    )
)
order by sid
```

Comment: Hi praveen. Have small problem. When am use this query it takes quite a large time when there are huge records